What is the Best Way to Share Information Among My Team Using SharePoint and Teams for Collaborative Editing?
I am trying to determine the best way to share information amongst my team using SharePoint & Teams.
We have a group of people who all need access to files for collaborative editing.
I can see two ways:

Place the information in MS Teams Files tab. On SharePoint, this is accessible through the 'Documents' titled Sharepoint documents library (within the In Channel section); or
Place this information within a Sharepoint document library.

Either way, I will have users sync the files to their computer, and access it through file explorer.
The main difference I can see between the two ways of storing the information, is that placing the information in a SharePoint document library enables document version controls that placing them within teams does not.
I've found and read through these web page, but they don't provide an explanation on the intricacies between the two options.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/should-i-save-files-to-onedrive-or-sharepoint-d18d21a0-1f9f-4f6c-ac45-d52afa0a4a2e
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-your-computer-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88
Is there anything else I should know?

The main difference between storing files in the Teams Files tab (which is essentially a SharePoint document library) versus directly in a SharePoint document library isn't about version control, as both options offer versioning.
Option 1: Teams Files Tab (Within a Channel)
Integrated Collaboration: Files are directly tied to the Teams environment, making it easier to collaborate within the context of a specific conversation or project.
Simplified Access: Users who are already using Teams will find it convenient to access and edit documents without switching platforms.
Default SharePoint Library: Files stored here are actually stored in the underlying SharePoint site associated with the Team, specifically in the "Documents" library under a folder named after the channel.
Permissions: Permissions are tied to the Team, so if someone is a member of the Team, they automatically have access to these files.
Option 2: SharePoint Document Library
Custom Libraries and Structure: You have more flexibility in setting up custom document libraries, metadata, and folder structures that might better suit your organization’s needs.
Advanced Document Management: SharePoint libraries offer more advanced document management features like custom metadata, content types, and more granular permissions that might not be as easily accessible or configurable within the Teams interface.
Standalone Access: SharePoint libraries can be accessed independently of Teams, which might be beneficial if some users prefer or require direct access via SharePoint.
To sum up:

If your team primarily collaborates through Teams and you want everything in one place, using the Files tab within a channel is convenient and keeps things simple.

If you need more advanced document management features, custom metadata, or a more complex folder structure, storing files directly in a SharePoint document library might be better.



I'm very grateful. Since I wrote my post I realised that my comments regarding versioning were wrong, however I am grateful for the extra detail you've provided.
Do you know of a middle ground, something that provides Sharepoint advanced document management features, but improves ease of use for end users? Most find teams easy to use, but clunky to access files through an app. Most end up syncing or adding a shortcut to OneDrive in order to access the files via the File Explorer. Though I'm not sure if we're losing out on the document management features as a result.

Ease of use is a very subjective expression. I find both super easy to use, but I do nothing else 8-9 hours a day.
I can imagine for someone whose main job doesn't rely on sitting in Teams or SPO, it can be quite challenging to get used to the features, but that's what you like about the solution, right? The advanced document management features?
So..... what's left? User training?
